# Any one knows any book template for IOS App

Tags: iphone, ios

I need a template like cover flow for viewing books in IOS App. Anybody knows any template which can show books.

Please find attached images. I need something like shown in figure.

Sorry but I do not know these question should be ask on stack overflow or other stack overflow options!
[image]

Comment: Probably it is a Customized version of Cover flow. Also you can use [UIPageViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to achieve this we have a number of controls. Please go through these

[Pepper UI](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/icarousel)

[Flip View Control](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mpflipviewcontroller)

[Leaves Control](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/leaves)

[Page Curl](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pagecurl)

You would have to tweak all of them to get your desired animation though iCarousel does offer many such animations. Dont forget to go through its library. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) which is open source well-known library for such formats. You need to tweak the in-built types a little to make it look like a book.

Set the type to `iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2` and implement delegate method `itemTransformForOffset` to provide your custom transform for book-like display.